# Check visibillity of element based on Opacity

Tags: capybara

I have an element that is hidden with a button click, but for cosmetic reason we are hiding it by changing the opacity. How can I check that the opacity of this element is 0 using Capybara?

```
<div class="row lower-section" style="opacity: 0; ">
```

Unfortunately is_visible() [doesn't check](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/master/lib/capybara/node/simple.rb#L97) CSS.

Thanks,

Mike

Answer (score 1):

I would try using xpath to locate the button and check its style tag.
Somthing like...

```
page.should have_xpath(:xpath, "//div[@class='row lower-section' @style='opacity: 0;')
```

should work.

Check the docs for more info 
https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara

Answer (score 1):

I've found jQuery to work best for these sorts of things. I've found that using xpaths is far too fickle- especially if you're web testing instead of rack testing. I'd do something like this:

```
Given I do something
Then I should see that "element" has "opacity" value "0"

Then /^I should see that "([^\"]*)" has "([^\"]*)" value "([^\"]*)"$/ do |element,   
   property,value|
 @result = page.evaluate_script("$('#{element}').css('#{property}');")
 @result.should eql(value), "expected #{property} on #{element} to be #{value}"
end
```